# Function Definition not recognized

Tags: c++

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<bool> row;
typedef vector<row> matrix;


//Corner functions
int population_tlc(int x, int y, matrix& grid)
{
    int popu;
    for(int yi = y+1; yi >= y; y--)
    {
        for(int xi = x+1; xi >= x; x--)
        {
           if (grid[yi][xi] == true)
           {
               popu++;
           }
        }
    }
    return popu;
}

int population_trc(int x, int y, matrix& grid)
{
    int popu;
    for(int yi = y+1; yi >= y; y--)
    {
        for(int xi = x-1; xi <= x; x++)
        {
           if (grid[yi][xi] == true)
           {
               popu++;
           }
        }
    }
    return popu;
}

int population_blc(int x, int y, matrix& grid)
{
    int popu;
    for(int yi = y-1; yi <= y; y++)
    {
        for(int xi = x-1; xi >= x; x--)
        {
           if (grid[yi][xi] == true)
           {
               popu++;
           }
        }
    }
    return popu;
}


int population_brc(int x, int y, matrix& grid)
{
    int popu;
    for(int yi = y-1; yi <= y; y++)
    {
        for(int xi = x-1; xi <= x; x++)
        {
           if (grid[yi][xi] == true)
           {
               popu++;
           }
        }
    }
    return popu;
}
//Edge functions
int population_left(int x, int y, matrix& grid)
{
    int popu;
    for(int yi = y-1; yi <= y+1; y++)
    {
        for(int xi = x; xi<= x+1; x++)
        {
            if(xi == x && yi == y)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (grid[yi][xi] == true)
           {
               popu++;
           }
    }
    return popu;
}


int population_top(int x, int y, matrix& grid)
{
    int popu;
    for(int yi = y; yi <= y+1; y++)
    {
        for(int xi = x-1; xi<= x+1; x++)
        {
            if(xi == x && yi == y)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (grid[yi][xi] == true)
           {
               popu++;
           }
        }
    }
    return popu;
}

int population_right(int x, int y, matrix& grid)
{
    int popu;
    for(int yi = y-1; yi <= y+1; y++)
    {
        for(int xi = x-1; xi<= x; x++)
        {
            if(xi == x && yi == y)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (grid[yi][xi] == true)
           {
               popu++;
           }
        }
    }
    return popu;

}
```

I'm trying to make a program that imitates conway's game of life.  These functions take x and y coordinates as well as a reference of the grid in main. The functions check the surroundings of the x and y coordinate point in the grid and decide whether it should be true(alive) or false(dead). The problem is that in the last two functions, the IDE keeps prompting me for a `;` even though im defining the function. I also have a header guard full of all the function prototypes.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<bool> row;
typedef vector<row> matrix;

int population_tlc(int x, int y, matrix& grid);
int population_trc(int x, int y, matrix& grid);
int population_blc(int x, int y, matrix& grid);
int population_brc(int x, int y, matrix& grid);
int population_left(int x, int y, matrix& grid);
int population_top(int x, int y, matrix& grid);
int population_right(int x, int y, matrix& grid);
int population_bottom(int x, int y, matrix& grid);
```

My question is how to do I get it to "realize" that it is a function definition and an incomplete function prototype.  Thank you in advance

Comment: It's a good thing that you indented your code, because in the function before the two last ones, there's a missing right brace. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: hence, the usage of vi/vim is always a better choice :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing `}` in this function:

```
int population_left(int x, int y, matrix& grid)
{
    int popu;
    for(int yi = y-1; yi <= y+1; y++)
    {
        for(int xi = x; xi<= x+1; x++)
        {
            if(xi == x && yi == y)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (grid[yi][xi] == true)
           {
               popu++;
           }
    }
    return popu;
}
```

So replace it by:

```
int population_left(int x, int y, matrix& grid)
{
    int popu;
    for(int yi = y-1; yi <= y+1; y++)
    {
        for(int xi = x; xi<= x+1; x++)
        {
            if(xi == x && yi == y)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (grid[yi][xi] == true)
            {
               popu++;
            }
         }
    }
    return popu;
}
```

You can find some editors or IDE that may highlight this kind of typo for you ;) (emacs for instance)